# How to convert text in pandas dataframe column into one hot encoded columns based on the unique column values found which are separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, one-hot-encoding

How to convert comma separated text in pandas data frame column into one hot encoded columns based on the  unique column values found. Here is the pic and expected columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLBkG.png)

Comment: Could you add the dataframe in code? (try to always avoid images)

Comment: Please provide an example input and example output. Do not use images.